# Vuejs showing evaluation v-if before data

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

Ok, the question is vague, but I have a code that looks like this:

```
<template>
  <div>
      <p v-if="users" v-for="user in users"> {{ user.name}} </p>
      <p v-else> No users found</p>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    data() {
      return {
        users: null
      }
    },

    created() {
      var that = this 
      axios.get('...').then(response => {
          that.users = response.data
      }).catch(error => { .... })
    }
  }
</script>
```

So, the actuall script has no issues, it loads the users and shows it properly. But, always I see the `No users founds` before vuejs loads the users. I don't want to see that messages, unless `users` is `null` but it seems vue doesn't wait for that to be true before showing the `v-else`.

Is there any proper way to handle this

Comment: You cannot solve this problem like you want to: The website loads fast - but loading the users is an asynchronous action! Loading the users may take 3 seconds - in this time there are no users, users **is** really null. What do you expect the user to see in this 3 seconds while waiting for the user-list ? A blank page? A loading spinner?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Instead of using users for the if/else, use a loading property (you would probably need it anyway to present a loading state to the user):

```
<template>
  <div>
      <p v-if="!loading && users.length" v-for="user in users"> {{ user.name}} </p>
      <p v-else> No users found</p>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    data() {
      return {
        users: null,
        loading: true
      }
    },

    created() {
      var that = this 

      axios.get('...').then(response => {
          that.users = response.data
          that.loading = false
      }).catch(error => {that.loading = false .... })
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: This seems like an ugly hack. I had tought about it, but it would mess up my code.

Comment: It's not a hack, it's the common way of doing it, and like i said, you probably need it anyway to display a loading message to the user (you don't want the user waiting for the data to load without knowing that you are loading the data), try setting the network to slow 3G(in dev tools) and see how much time you need to wait

Comment: if i may ask, why do you use that instead of this in the axios.then statement?

Answer (score 1):

I think this code is better:

```
<template>
  <div>
      <p v-for="user in users"> {{ user.name}} </p>
      <p v-if="isLoaded && user.length === 0"> No users found</p>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    data() {
      return {
        isLoaded: false,
        users: []
      }
    },

    created() {
      var that = this 
      axios.get('...').then(response => {
          that.users = response.data
          that.isLoaded = true
      }).catch(error => { .... })
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: he will have the same problem since users.length would be 0 until data is loaded

Comment: If `users` is null, then the first evaluated expression i.e. `user.name` will throw an erro

Comment: @hidar - it won't since vue will not render this part